# Mapping route for Account/Login HTTP post

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/843044/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-The

I've been building an ASP.NET + AngularJS app using the tutorial in the link above.

```
$scope.login = function () {
    console.log("DERP");
    var result = LoginFactory($scope.loginForm.emailAddress, $scope.loginForm.password, $scope.loginForm.rememberMe);
    result.then(function (result) {
        if (result.success) {
            if ($scope.loginForm.returnUrl !== undefined) {
                console.log("im in");
                $location.path('/home');
            } else {
                console.log("login failed");
                $location.path($scope.loginForm.returnUrl);
            }
        } else {
            $scope.loginForm.loginFailure = true;
        }
    });
}
```

When executing this function, the HTTP POST request runs for a time and then returns with an Internal Server error. It does not return a success or failure.

```
POST http://localhost:54865/Account/Login 500 (Internal Server Error)
  (anonymous function) @ angular.js:8495
  t @ angular.js:8291
  g @ angular.js:8025
  J @ angular.js:11498
  J @ angular.js:11498
  (anonymous function) @ angular.js:11584
  k.$eval @ angular.js:12608
  k.$digest @ angular.js:12420
  k.$apply @ angular.js:12712
  (anonymous function) @ angular.js:18980
  (anonymous function) @ angular.js:2823
  q @ angular.js:325c @ angular.js:2822
```

I am fairly new to ASP.NET MVC so I do not have a good grasp on the concepts. But I suspect that the trouble lies in my `RouteConfig.cs` file, where the tutorial has instructed me to explicitly state all the various routes for each of my AngularJS views. The only `/Account/Login` route I have is the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "login",
    url: "Account/Login",
    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login" });
```

If I were to create an MVC route to accept HTTP POST requests to Account/Login, how would I implement this? Am I totally off-track?

**EDIT**

Here are the relevant pieces of my `AccountController.cs` file:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<bool> Login(MyApp.Entities.ViewModels.LoginViewModel model)
{
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);
    switch (result)
    {
       case SignInStatus.Success:
            return true;
       default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your request seems to be hitting the MVC controller. You can try to put breakpoint on the server code and see what the error is. For Angular you have not added the error callback (second) parameter in `then` to receive http error. Also share your controller methods

Comment: You don't need a route mapping of `Account/Login` for a controller and an action, your original `{controller}/{action}/{id}` will handle this sufficiently for you.

Comment: @Coulton As per the instructions of the tutorial in Part 2, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806500/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-P, I mapped these routes manually to avoid a 404 server error.

Comment: @Chandermani I have added the two controller methods to my question.